# General approach for (equivalent of) "backreferences within character class"?

Tags: regex, perl, backreference, character-class

In Perl regexes, expressions like `\1`, `\2`, etc. are usually interpreted as "backreferences" to previously captured groups, but not so when the `\1`, `\2`, etc. appear within a character class.  In the latter case, the `\` is treated as an escape character (and therefore `\1` is just `1`, etc.).

Therefore, if (for example) one wanted to match a string (of length greater than 1) whose first character matches its last character, but does not appear anywhere else in the string, the following regex will *not* do:

```
/\A       # match beginning of string;
 (.)      # match and capture first character (referred to subsequently by \1);
 [^\1]*   # (WRONG) match zero or more characters different from character in \1;
 \1       # match \1;
 \z       # match the end of the string;
/sx       # s: let . match newline; x: ignore whitespace, allow comments
```

would *not* work, since it matches (for example) the string `'a1a2a'`:

```
  DB<1> ( 'a1a2a' =~ /\A(.)[^\1]*\1\z/ and print "fail!" ) or print "success!"
fail!
```

I can usually manage to find some workaround<sup>1</sup>, but it's always rather problem-specific, and usually far more complicated-looking than what I would do if I could use backreferences within a character class.

**Is there a *general* (and hopefully straightforward) workaround?**

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> For example, for the problem in the example above, I'd use something like</sub>

```
/\A
 (.)              # match and capture first character (referred to subsequently
                  # by \1);
 (?!.*\1\.+\z)    # a negative lookahead assertion for "a suffix containing \1";
 .*               # substring not containing \1 (as guaranteed by the preceding
                  # negative lookahead assertion);
 \1\z             # match last character only if it is equal to the first one
/sx
```

<sub>...where I've replaced the reasonably straightforward (though, alas, incorrect) subexpression `[^\1]*` in the earlier regex with the somewhat more forbidding negative lookahead assertion `(?!.*\1.+\z)`.  This assertion basically says "give up if `\1` appears anywhere beyond this point (other than at the last position)."  Incidentally, I give this solution just to illustrate the sort of workarounds I referred to in the question.  I don't claim that it is a particularly good one.</sub>

Comment: The accepted solution is perfect for negation, but won't cover some other uses of character classes, such as ranges. Suppose you wanted to match all sequences of 3 digits in non-decreasing order (so "111", "123", "368", "449", but not "987" or "322").  Using backrefs in character classes, the pseudo-regex would be `/^([0-9])([\1-9])([\2-9])$/`, but you can't accomplish the same as simply with a negative lookahead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a negative lookahead within a repeated group:

```
/\A         # match beginning of string;
 (.)        # match and capture first character (referred to subsequently by \1);
 ((?!\1).)* # match zero or more characters different from character in \1;
 \1         # match \1;
 \z         # match the end of the string;
/sx
```

This pattern can be used even if the group contains more than one character.