# Regex Capturing: repeating two letters

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to check if a word have three or more repeating 'two letters pare', But the expressing returns true only if **the same** letter is repeated. Why?

```
(([a-z])([^\1]))\1\2{2,} 
    ^      ^     ^ ^  ^
    1      2     3 4  5
```

1) any letter (captured set \1)
2) any character that is not set 1 (captured set \2)
3) captured \1 again
4) captured \2 again
5) at least twice

words that should return TRUE:
asasasassafasf, ereeeerererere, dddddtrtrtrtruuuuuuuu

words that should return FALSE:
dddddddd, rrrrrrrrrrlkajf, fffffffssssssytytfffffff

Comment: Backreferences don't work within character classes (after all they might be comprised of more than one symbol). See [General approach for (equivalent of) "backreferences within character class"?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18242119) for the lookahead alternative.

Comment: Few examples will greatly help to clarify your problem.

Comment: @anubhava asasasas bhbhbhbhbh blaytytytyt...

Comment: You really need to give us examples. There are several interpretations to `have three or more repeating 'two letters pairs'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this using a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
([a-z])((?!\1)[a-z])(?:\1\2){2,}
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/aF0yA8/1).

**Explanation:**

```
([a-z])  # Match and capture a single ASCII letter in group 1
(        # Match and capture...
 (?!\1)  # unless it's the same letter as the one captured before
 [a-z]   # a single ASCII letter in group 2
)        # End of group 2
(?:\1\2) # Match those two letters
{2,}     # two or more times
```

Comment: As you pointed out in a comment in my answer, the two letters must be different, +1 for implementing that.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your short description following regex should work for you:

```
(([a-z])((?!\2)[a-z]))\1{2}
```

#### [Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/rN3tR2/3)

- `([a-z])` - matches letters a to z and capture them in a group
- `\2` - Back reference to group #2
- `(?!\2)[a-z])` - matches letters a to z that is NOT group #2
- `\1{2}` 2 instances of back reference #1

OR using **relative back reference numbering**:

```
(([a-z])(?!\g{-1})[a-z])\1{2}
```

**In short this regex matches 3 consecutive occurrences of a letter pair of different characters.**

Comment: but also returns one letter that repeat itself like: dddddddddddddd

Comment: Thank you! but why is the negative lookahead **\2** and not \1?

Comment: It is because `\1` represents `(([a-z])((?!\2)[a-z]))` and `\2` represents `([a-z])`

Comment: but if it is first, why is it \2 and not \1?

Comment: Whatever starts first is numbers `1`. So outer `(..)` is numbers `1` and inner `([a-z])` is numbered `2`

Comment: Also I updated answer to show use of relative back reference numbering  .